# Puxando informações de uma tabela para uma página de notícias

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma página de notícias que puxa pelo `id` (é uma daquelas `noticias.php?id=1`), mas queria que ela contasse só os comentários da  notícia que estou lendo, e não de todas. Isso é possível?

Eu já consegui o PHP para contar, mas queria dar essa especificada.

**PHP para contar:**

```
 <?php
 $contador = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) as total FROM 10cms_noticias_resp 
                         WHERE id_noticia = id_noticia") or die(mysql_error());

$comentario = mysql_fetch_assoc($contador);
 ?>
 <?php echo $comentario['total'];

  ?>
```

**PHP da minha página:**

```
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
 $noticiass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 10cms_noticias WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error()); ?> 
 <?php $i = 0; while($edit = mysql_fetch_assoc($noticiass)){ $i++; ?>
```

Comment: Qual é o problema @Kloves?

Comment: é porque conta todos os comentários, não conta só o da notícia que eu tô lendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
$contador = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) as total FROM 10cms_noticias_resp 
                     WHERE id_noticia = id_noticia") or die(mysql_error());
```

Essa primeira cláusula `WHERE` está errada. O `id_noticia` sempre vai ser igual a ele mesmo.
Tu tem que passar ali um valor (ou uma variável) que corresponda ao `id` da notícia que tu queres consultar.

Comment: WOW! Consegui, muito obrigado.